# Fetch random town names based on countries

Tags: python, random, geocoding, geonames

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and I've gotten somewhere between having it work once in a blue moon and completely breaking down.

My ultimate goal is to replace the "!R"s in the dictionary with a random town names from a region/country the user can chose from. Or for a concrete example, basically this kind of thing: https://www.mithrilandmages.com/utilities/CityNames.php

After starting to simply go online and copy-paste lists of town names into a .csv I realised that would take way to long and would be by far not exhaustive enough, and there are databases set up for this.

So I tried to get something working using [GeoCoder](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/index.html) and [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org)...but I simply can't seem to make it work as I want it to work (or efficiently for that matter).

**Link to the script and code**: https://github.com/Araxiel/CK2-Province_Set-Upper/blob/abandoned/1.3.0/Source/_workbench/databases.py

My current attempt was to just use `children` all the way down to the smallest child, but it's not very reliable and the queries take a while. Further, I can't seem to get something like `United States` work as a name.
All the info I can find is to return specific longtitudes or IP addresses of specified locations, but that's far from what I'm looking for. I saw a library called "Faker", but I'm quite sure that's not what I'm looking for either, especially since I can't find any documentation on where its databases take their information from.

I'm just about ready to throw in the towel and try my hand at creating a RNG name generator that assembles words together.

**Edit:** Basically, my current attempt with the following...

```
    def get_towns(country):
        import geocoder
        global geonames_username
        a = geocoder.geonames(country, key=geonames_username)
        b = geocoder.geonames(a.geonames_id, key=geonames_username, method='children')
        import random
        b_r = random.choice(b)
        c = geocoder.geonames(b_r.geonames_id, key=geonames_username, method='children')
        [...etc...]
```

...breaks down when I try to put in `"United States"` as country, it for some reasons returns `South America`. And even if I could solve this issue, just all the way down to children with 4-5 queries is not only incredibly inefficient (ending up taking about 10 second to get to the town, meaning at 50 queries it might take 10 minutes [and cost me 200 credits; it's a small program that only a handful of people will ever use so I won't exhaust the 50k queries a day, but that can't be good coding]), but it also seems to break down more often than not (see the United States example). 
My question is basically if there is anything obvious I'm missing, like a direct way to get a selection of random town names either through GeoNames or anything other way. And bundling the nearly 2gb of .txt files is obviously not an option.

Comment: Please include the relevant code here in your posting. Your description here also doesn make it clear to me what *exact* problem you try to solve; you describe the general problem (that's good) and mention a few approaches to that which you tried and link one of your solution attempts. But it is missing what exactly goes wrong there and why.

Comment: What happens if your links are down or your links contents changes? The answer to both of these questions is why you should put your code directly into your question. Do not just copy/paste, reduce it to the minimal needed to replicate your problem - see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide demodata.

Comment: Updated my post